# Status code 200 but still data not loading in server end

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit

In my Android app, for update profile page I am using API, and when I call the API the response is showing success and I check the status code 200 but the data is not loaded in database, using Postman the data is loaded correctly but from my phone the data is not loaded,

One day before it is working file but today it is not adding data, even I don't change a single word or line in code.

The API is post API, and it is use form-data for data,

Below is my API code

**API Handler Class**

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiHandler {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://rndtd.com/demos/scrapbazar/api/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        if(retrofit == null){

          
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Interface for API endpoint**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("allProducts")
    Call<List<List<Product>>> getAllProducts();

  @Multipart
    @POST("updateprofile")
    Call<ResponseBody> updateUserProfile(
            @Part("id") int id,
            @Part("first_name") String userName,
            @Part("email") String email,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image
            );

}
```

**Method where I call the API**

```
 public void updateProfile() {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);

        int id = SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(this);
        String userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        if (userName.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || selectedImageUri == null) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return; // Exit the method if any field is missing
        }

        if (selectedImageUri != null) {
            String fileName = getFileName(selectedImageUri);
           
            File imageFile = new File(getCacheDir(), fileName);

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            RequestBody imageRequestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getMimeType(selectedImageUri)), imageFile);
            MultipartBody.Part imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.getName(), imageRequestFile);

            Log.d("Request Data", "ID: " + id);
            Log.d("Request Data", "UserName: " + userName);
            Log.d("Request Data", "Email: " + email);
            Log.d("Request Data", "image: " + imagePart);

            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.updateUserProfile(id, userName, email, imagePart);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                    int responseCode = response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "code : " + responseCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        String msg = "Customer Updated Successfully";
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Response is not success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Log.e("Tag", "Error : " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Error " + t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

When I am check the logcat then the data is showing correctly :

**My log in logcat are:**

**ID: 2**

**UserName: myName**

**Email: myName@gmail.com**

**image: okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part@2afca0d**

Comment: check the response body and call.request.url  as well

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli check the request url and url is correct and the response is only one message {
    "message": "Customer updated successfully"
}

Comment: That means Api is successfull. The errror is somewhereelse